# addClass() work but it has a css priority issue

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, priority-queue

So I want to addClass() in another class but that doesn't work correctly.

In scss I have:

```
body {
 main {
   section.theory {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    top: 100vh;
    background-color: $white;
    box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px #cfcfcf;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
 }

 .J-bigSection-visible {
   top: 100px;
 }      
}
```

And in javascript i have:

```
$('#theory-trigger').on('click', function(){
   $('section.theory').addClass('J-bigSection-visible');
});
```

When i see the page source the DOM reads the function and add the class, but the css isn't applied. it appears underline, so the top:100vh stays.

If i write .css({'top':'100px'}); on jQuery it works, but in this project I want to stay only with css.
What am I doing wrong? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SCSS, you need to move `.J-bigSection-visible {top: 100px;}` inside of the `section.theory` block. This will add the necessary specificity.

**SCSS**

```
body {
 main {
   section.theory {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    top: 100vh;
    background-color: $white;
    box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px #cfcfcf;
    overflow: hidden;

    &.J-bigSection-visible {
      top: 100px;
    } 
   }
 }     
}
```

EDIT: Answers two comment questions.

First question, you can use the same class. You just have to change the SCSS to reflect that:

**SCSS**

```
body {
     main {
       section.theory {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
        top: 100vh;
        background-color: $white;
        box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px #cfcfcf;
        overflow: hidden;

        &.J-bigSection-visible {
          top: 100px;
        } 
       }
       section.practice {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
        top: 100vh;
        background-color: $white;
        box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px #cfcfcf;
        overflow: hidden;

        &.J-bigSection-visible {
          top: 100px;
        } 
       }
     }     
    }
```

Second question: yes, you can `addClass` to an element with an `ID`. You just need to change the jQuery to be `$('#elementWithID').addClass('yourClass');`

**NOTE:** This will add a **CLASS** to your element, as your elements can only have a single **ID**

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked :D But now imagine that I have another div: section.practice. And i want to add the same class "J-bigSection-visible", how do I do what? Do I need to create another .J-bigSection-visible2 inside that section.practice or there is a way to duplicate the class?

Comment: As this answers your original question, please mark it as accepted. I'll create an edit to answer your comment.

Comment: thanks, i'm new here so i don't know very well how this works. I tried to add a class to an id, but it didn't work because ID has more priority than a class... so i turn all my id into classes... now it's working like a charm.

Comment: `id` does have more priority, but you can still add a `class` to an element with an `id`, which if nested in your CSS will give that element more priority. Your SCSS would look like this: `#element-id { (styles) &.element-class {(styles)}}`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing CSS wrong.

`body main section.theory` is more specific than `body .J-bigSection-visible`

Try `section.J-bigSection-visible` and move it inside the `main` block - this will have the same specificity, and since it comes later in the sheet it will override.

In a more general case, if such a fix isn't available, you may consider using `top: 100px !important;` to force an override.

Comment: I tried the first solution but it doesn't work... and about !important i don't want to use it :/ i tried to put .J-bigSection-visible out of body and it doesn't work neither.